1974 dodge b300 sportsman RV won't run
Ok so here's the story. I've had this RV for a little over a year. I had it running before. But didn't drive it far. After starting the engine would die if I did not continue to hold down the gas pedal. Once it warmed up it would idle and then drive. However, when shifting from reverse to drive or even into drive or reverse, I'd have to feather the gas pedal to keep it from stalling. When driving it was sluggish and had very little power on slight incline. It seemed that the carburetor wasn't receiving enough gas.
One day, it would not turn over any more. Looking into the carburetor I noticed the jets would not shoot gas when trying to start. So I assumed it was an issue with the fuel pumps or a clog in the gas line or tank. I let it sit for a long time.
When getting back to it, I pulled the inlet gas line from the fuel pump and ran a short gas line directly to a gas can. Boom! It started up and idled great. I turned it off planning to change gas lines and check the sock in the tank. But I needed to move it a half a mile. So later when I came back to move it next day, with the gas line into the small gas tank next to me like the previous day, now it will not turn over again. I'm very confused. I also noticed this time that the jets seemed to be putting more gas than necessary (still feeding gas when not pressing pedal or trying to turn the engine over for about 5 seconds. Also noticed around the carburetor was small amount of gas coated on the outside of the carb. Idk what the problem is. Thought it was the clogged gas line to tank but now I'm unsure. Please help. Thanks so much. UPDATE: After letting it sit for a couple days I came back to it and decided to try and start it again. And of course it starts up and ran it for a minute or so before I shut it off. So now I am even more stumped. Why will it not run a day after having run it then let it sit for two days and having done nothing to it, runs no problem?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it this is using a mechanical fuel pump which is directly connected to the engine? Which engine is it? I would suspect it's either a 318 or 360 V8?

I believe it's the 360 V8 with Holley carb. And yes it has a mechanical fuel pump. Someone had added a cheap in line fuel pump that the wires weren't even connected. I removed it and replaced the lines between the fuel filter and the original metal fuel line.

If it had an inline pump, I'd double check to make sure the mechanical one is working okay.

A relative left his Mazda RX-7 sitting unused for several years until it was decided to sell it. The four barrel carburetor was fouled up with gelled fuel in its jets. I carefully disassembled it to find more blockages, cleaned out old fuel and the engine roared back to life. Fuel pressure on carburetors are around 7 psi if you can test it. Mechanical fuel pumps can fail from a worn out diaphragm.

Do you know where I can find some good info on how to take mine apart. I'm a pretty Capable guy but I've never worked on carburetors and the thought of taking it apart and then not being able to properly adjust it when it goes back on makes me a lil hesitant.
